Windows Presentation Framework (WPF) Markup Contol for CSS
I am developing a VSTO adding for Visio that has a modal dialog / form that enables the user to edit CSS classes for rendering Visio models in SVG format, and to be able to see the results immediately in a WebView2 embedded browser control (a bit like JSfiddle).
I would like to display the markup for editting the CSS like an IDE, e.g. Visual Studio Code ...etc. However, the only two controls that I can see are RichTextBox and TextBox. Neither seem quite suited to the task.
Is there any other control, whether WPF or third party?
Thanks and regards,
Andrew
